# How to make a zoom in function when the website opens

Tags: css, animation, zoom-sdk

How can i make a code where if you open my webpage then this happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGsKzZtRwxw using css?

But what i want instead is for the logo to first zoom in (faster, maybe 5 sec until the animation is over) to show the logo, then it goes to the top left where it stays there when you browse through my page. It is for a school project with the theme star wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like in below snippet (using animation) :

> Use styles and decoration according to need , this is only a demo.

> As known font-size is for text so this animation will work only for text . If you want animation for other stuffs than change accordingly like can use `width` `height` higher values or can use `transform: scale()` property

```js
function zoom() {
  var reed = document.getElementById("demo");
  reed.classList.add("animation");
}
```

```css
.animation {
  animation: zoomer 5s linear;
}

@keyframes zoomer {
  0% {
    font-size: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

.color {
  color: red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="zoom()">
  <h1 id="demo" class="color">content</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CSS zoom rule:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "300%" 
        }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
<h6>content</h6>
</body>
```

Note: It just makes everything on the page bigger

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that when the page is fully loaded you set the logo style to have an animation which starts with transform with a scale from 1 to something and then moves to top 0 left 0 (or whatever is suitable).

Without seeing your actual code it is difficult to advise further but something like:

```
@keyframes logo {
  0% {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  50% {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
    transform: scale(2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  } 
  100% {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
}
```